# Node cmd files going to root instead of .bin folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-install, node-modules, vue-cli-3

I've been trying to start a project with the vue cli template, but when I npm install I get a bunch of cmd files in the root!

[image]

I have checked my environment variables too and they seem correct. Does anyone know why this is happening?

[image]

I'm using node v8.11.4 on Windows 10, using VS Code as my IDE. I've also noticed my node_modules folder doesn't have a .bin folder in it.

I have tried reinstalling it multiple times, as well as creating create-react-app where the npm install does the same thing.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This is exactly why i make my own start kits :)